# Using swift and TwitterKit, NSURLRequest timeout after 10 seconds, After that all requests timeout automatically untill I close app and launch it

Tags: twitter, nsurlrequest

I am using swift 2.1 and TwitterKit facing error continously as NSURLRequest timeout, How should I increase timeout Interval.??

Comment: You might have better luck asking on a forum dedicated to Twitter Kit rather than a general networking forum.  The problem is probably specific to that API—either a broken version of the kit itself or a mistake in the way you're using it.

Comment: @dgatwood Thank you .